# How to get customised error message defined in Json Schema using json-schema-validator in java?

Tags: java, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am trying to access customised error message set in json schema in my java code if validation fails. But I am not able to fetch that. Can you please help me in finding a way ?

Library Plugin

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.networknt</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.49</version>
    </dependency>
```

Json-Schema

```
 "membershipNo": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1,
      "message": {
        "pattern": "membershipNo should not be empty"
      }
    }
```

This is how I am fetching the error in Java Class-

```
JsonSchema schema = JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance(SpecVersion.VersionFlag.V7).getSchema(schemaAsStream);
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    om.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategies.KEBAB_CASE);
    JsonNode jsonNode = om.readTree(payload);
    Set<ValidationMessage> errors = schema.validate(jsonNode);
    for (ValidationMessage error : errors) {
        System.out.println(error.getMessage());
    }

Error Getting- $.payment.membershipNo: must be at least 1 characters long"  
Error Expected - membershipNo should not be empty
```

Comment: Which library do you use for json validation?

Comment: @Nemanja edit my question. Added library details

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://github.com/networknt/json-schema-validator/blob/master/doc/cust-msg.md) you can provide the custom message in the json schema itself but not in the way you did.

For example if you have JSON schema like this ( with default message) :

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The person's first name."
    },
    "foo": {
      "type": "array",
      "maxItems": 3
    }
  }
}
```

You can customize the error messagge by changing above JSON schema as follows:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "The person's first name."
    },
    "foo": {
      "type": "array",
      "maxItems": 3
    }
  },
  "message": {
    "maxItems" : "MaxItem must be 3 only",
    "type" : "Invalid type"
  }
}
```

In the message field users can declare their custom message. The key should be the validation type, and the value should be the custom message.

```
"message": {
    [validationType] : [customMessage]
  }
```

Also, we can make format the dynamic message with properties returned from [ValidationMessage.java](https://github.com/networknt/json-schema-validator/blob/master/src/main/java/com/networknt/schema/ValidationMessage.java)class such as arguments, path e.t.c.

Take a look at the [PR](https://github.com/networknt/json-schema-validator/pull/438)

With this setup, this line of code:

```
 for (ValidationMessage error : errors) {
        System.out.println(error.getMessage());
    }
```

Should print your customized error message.

Comment: Seems likely your want to put the "maxItems" message inside "foo", so you can have a different message for each array (of there were more arrays):  `"foo": { ..., "message": { "maxItems": "foo must contain 3 or fewer entries" } }`